# Check to see if child divs are empty to remove attribute from parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that has submenu items that have drop downs and some that are just single links. I am working on this for touch devices, and I remove the href attribute for the submenu items that have a dropdown. I am wanting to check if the child elements are empty to not remove the href attribute so those links work. I have tried a bunch of things, but to no avail. Below is what I have at this point, I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
<li class="sub-menu-dropdown-toggle">
  <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="nav-link nav-link-sub-menu">Menu Item</a>
  <div class="sub-menu-dropdown">
    <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content">Some of these have content</div>
    <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content">Some of these have content</div>
    <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content"></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

```
const $emptyContent = $('.sub-menu-content');       
const $noFollow = $('.nav-link-sub-menu');

if ($emptyContent.is(':empty').trim()) {
  $noFollow.removeAttr('href');
}
```

Comment: Why are you performing a `trim()` on [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) result if it returns a boolean ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I have been trying everything at this point, nothing has seemed to work

Comment: @Pete For the touch devices I want the menu link to only open the dropdown, but some submenu items wont have drop downs and will be links only. The issue here is that this is shopify, and the liquid tags pull in this data into the divs. If there is no drop down on a menu link the div will still exist but will be empty. If that is the case, that means it will be a link that needs to work. So I have been trying to reference the empty div in order to not remove the href from that link. I have tried looping through etc, but nothing seems to be working and I feel it could be my syntax or something.

Comment: @Pete Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure JavaScript, you can just retrieve all the `<li>` elements using the **[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** method and then use the **[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method and the **[innerText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)** property to check if the dropdown menus are empty or not.

If a dropdown menu is not empty, you can use the **[removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)** property to remove the `href` attribute from the child anchor link.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```js
/* JavaScript */

var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu-dropdown-toggle");

lists.forEach(list => {
 if (list.children[1].innerText.length > 0) { // check if the dropdown div has any text inside or not
   list.children[0].removeAttribute("href"); // remove href attribute if it does
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<ul>
  <li class="sub-menu-dropdown-toggle">
    <a href="abc.html" class="nav-link nav-link-sub-menu">Menu Item 1</a>
    <div class="sub-menu-dropdown">
      <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content">Some of these have content</div>
      <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content">Some of these have content</div>
      <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu-dropdown-toggle">
    <a href="abc.html" class="nav-link nav-link-sub-menu">Menu Item 2</a>
    <div class="sub-menu-dropdown">
      <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content"></div>
      <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content"></div>
      <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu-dropdown-toggle">
  <a href="abc.html" class="nav-link nav-link-sub-menu">Menu Item 3</a>
  <div class="sub-menu-dropdown">
    <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content">Some of these have content</div>
    <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content">Some of these have content</div>
    <div class="row justify-content-between sub-menu-content"></div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Testing this out, it worked perfectly. I feel like I was getting all the "li" elements with a few of the jQuery functions I wrote, but it just never seemed to work 100%. Thank you very much for this, it helped me greatly!